# Check if ClassPathResource is file or folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot application, I'm currently using the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` this way to read the content of a folder (which may contain other files and folders) in my fat jar:

```
ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources  = resourcePatternResolver.getResources("data/**");
for (Resource resource : resources) {
    if (resource instanceof ClassPathResource) {
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = (ClassPathResource) resource;
        if (resource.contentLength() > 0) { // OUCH, empty files are not properly handled!
            // process file
        } else {
            // process folder
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem with the code above is that the condition `resource.contentLength() > 0` doesn't cover the corner case of empty files.

So, is there another way to check whether a `ClasspathResource` is actually a file or a folder?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225836/is-spring-resource-a-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use `isFile` method to find whether its a file, which is inherited from `AbstractFileResolvingResource` as mentioned in the documentation [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

so `resource.isFile()` will return true if its a file.

Comment: Unfortunately `ClassPathResource::isFile` returns `false` when running the application as a fat jar.

Comment: @Damith, you should have checked the API. [AbstractFileResolvingResource.isFile()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/AbstractFileResolvingResource.html#isFile--) always returns _false_.

Comment: sorry my bad, didn't really notice it.